# What can I do to my ListView changes between two different data types?

Tags: java, listview, javafx

Here's my listView:

```
public ListView<Consulta> lstViewLista;
```

Here I want my listView like it is (`listView<Consulta>`):

```
public void btnDireitaOnAction(ActionEvent event){
    ObservableList<Consulta> consultaData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        consultaData.addAll(ConsultaDAO.buscarPorData(Agenda.getData()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Erro: Impossível encontrar as consultas.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    lstViewLista.setItems(consultaData);
}
```

But here I want my listView like `listView<Paciente>`:

```
public void btnDireitaOnAction(ActionEvent event){
ObservableList<Paciente> pacienteData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
try {
    pacienteData.addAll(PacienteDAO.buscarPorData(Agenda.getData()));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Erro: Impossível encontrar os pacientes.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
lstViewLista.setItems(pacienteData);
```

}

How can I change between them? Someone help T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `lstViewLista` as being a `ListView` of type `<Consulta>`, so it's probably not wise to change it's type. Why not have two `ListView`s, one of type `<Consulta>` and one of type `<Paciente>`, like this?

```
ListView<Consulta> lstViewConsulta;
ListView<Paciente> lstViewPaciente;
```

You could switch which one is showing by either adding and removing it from it's parent node using `Node.getChildren()` or by using setManaged() and setVisible() like this:

```
//hide lstViewConsulta and show lstViewPaciente
lstViewConsulta.setVisible(false);
lstViewConsulta.setManaged(false);
lstViewPaciente.setVisible(true);
lstViewPaciente.setManaged(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, man. I was looking for something more "correct" to do, but I think that's a reasonable way of avoiding this little problem.

Comment: I mean, you could use `Object` if you really want, then you'd have a ListView<Object> and an ObservableList<Object>, but it honestly seems to me like you have two lists doing two different things, so I'd keep it as two ListViews if it were me.